# Flip the sort order of already sorted dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, numpy, sorting

I have a bunch of dataframes with the structure like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 'A', 10], [2, 'A', 20], [3, 'A', 30], 
     [1, 'B', 20], [2, 'B', 20], [3, 'B', 10],
     [1, 'M', 20], [2, 'M', 30], [3, 'M', 30]], 
    columns=['foo', 'bar', 'buzz']
)
```

the dataframe is initially sorted by columns `bar` and `foo` as one can get from

```
df.sort_values(['bar', 'foo'])
```

I need to get the `df` sorted by `foo` an `bar` instead. The obvious solution would be

```
df.sort_values(['foo', 'bar'])
```

which gives me

```
   foo bar  buzz
0    1   A    10
3    1   B    20
6    1   M    20
1    2   A    20
4    2   B    20
7    2   M    30
2    3   A    30
5    3   B    10
8    3   M    30
```

but the real-world dataframe contains about 500,000 rows and I have about 3,000 individual dataframes to be processed.

I was wondering if there is a better, more efficient solution which would take into account the fact that the dataframe is already pre-sorted?

Comment: Is there a particular reason the dataframe must be sorted in the reverse order? I want to make sure this isn't an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) before moving forward :)

Comment: Yes, the `foo` column corresponds to time and `bar` is a stock symbol. I need it for optimizing parquet files for time-based queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of stable sorting here, since `bar` is already sorted, which means that you only need to re-sort `foo`.

This should have a consistent impact on runtime at all sizes of DataFrame (I am seeing about a 2x speedup across the board).

Here is an example solution using `numpy`'s `argsort`, specifying a stable sort.

```
df.iloc[np.argsort(df['foo'], kind="stable")]
```

---

```
   foo bar  buzz
0    1   A    10
3    1   B    20
6    1   M    20
1    2   A    20
4    2   B    20
7    2   M    30
2    3   A    30
5    3   B    10
8    3   M    30
```

---

***Performance and Validation***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": np.random.randint(0, 100, 100_000),
        "bar": np.random.choice(list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"), 100_000),
        "buzz": np.random.randint(0, 100, 100_000),
    }
).sort_values(["bar", "foo"])

In [42]: %timeit df.iloc[np.argsort(df['foo'], kind="stable")]                                          
3.41 ms ± 22.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [43]: %timeit df.sort_values(["foo", "bar"])                                                         
6.95 ms ± 136 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [48]: a = df.iloc[np.argsort(df['foo'], kind="stable")]                                              

In [49]: b = df.sort_values(["foo", "bar"])                                                             

In [50]: np.all(a == b)                                                                                 
Out[50]: True
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe this is something I was looking for. It probably won't give me as much improvement as I expected but the approach itself is great

Comment: You could also use ``df.iloc[df.foo.argsort().array]``. I believe it is a wrapper on ``np.argsort``